# Strange BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

This may sound a newbie question however I'm new iOS dev,

recently I've switched to ARC and have got following issue in my code. I've implemented a class with following init method

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        TokenManager* tokenManager = [[TokenManager alloc] initWithApikey:<my valid token>];
        mRequest = [[GeoCodingRequest alloc] initWithApikey:apiKey withOptions:nil tokenManager:tokenManager];
        mRequest.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

where `mRequest` in interface is declared like this     `__strong GeoCodingRequest* mRequest;`

In my other method of the same class I send a message to `mRequest` like this

```
[mRequest findObject:<some valid array> around:<some valid location> withDistance:<some valid radius>];
```

When the message is sent to object app crashes with following message

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendRequestWithToken:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8974640'`

`findObject: around: withDistance:` - is a method from public library, so I've not access to its implementation.

Please help me to understand why this crash happens ?! 
I guess it is coming from ARC _*strong/*_weak qualifier usage or smth.

Comment: search about for NSZombieEnabled - this error almost always results from sending a bad method to an object, which can in-turn happen when an object is free'd and another allocated in the same location

Answer (score 1):

The message means that `mRequest` has been deallocated has that a string is now using the memory that had previously been allocated for `mRequest`.

You should run your app with Zombies enabled to understand when `mRequest` gets deallocated.

Comment: But doesn't __strong qualifier guarantee that it will remain living ?

Comment: basically I would like to know why it is getting dealloced ?

Comment: __strong should keep it alive, indeed. There must be another issue somewhere else in your code. Instruments will tell you where exactly your zombie object was deallocated. This will let you track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `tokenManager` isn't retained by the request (which is a bug in the library). As it isn't retained anywhere, the `tokenManager` is deallocated and a new object (here an instance of `NSString`) may be allocated at the same place.

You need to store the `tokenManager` in a strong **instance variable** (just as `mRequest`) in order to retain it as long as the request needs it.

Comment: making tokenManager member with __strong qualifier didn't help, it still crashes ...

Comment: Adding the __strong qualifier isn't enough: you need to declare the variable as an instance variable, just as you did for `mRequest`.

Comment: a quote from my previous message "making tokenManager member with __strong qualifier" ... so I did it already

Answer (score 0):

if you have any weak references try to use

```
MyObject * strongMyObject = weakMyObject;
if(strongMyObject){
   NSLog(@"This is not released");
}
```

It's a good practice when you have weak references. Try this.

Comment: I don't see any weak reference in the question. I don't know how that could help.

Comment: I don't see the interface in your question. I don't know how I could have known! You said "I guess it is coming from ARC _strong/_weak qualifier usage or smth." So one can understand that you might have used weak references.